# Imagen en IONIC, que mantenga el aspecto, o recorte la parte central de la imagen

Tags: javascript, ionic, scss

Me gustaria poner en una imagen en ionic 5

He intentado, hacerlo pero me estira la imagen o poner bordes negros.

No se si es posible, que mantenga es aspecto, y coja solamente una parte central con las mismas proporciones, sin estirar no poner bandas negras

Esto es lo que he probado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria conseguir esto, que recorte una parte, proporcionada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

css

```
ion-content.background{
    --background: url(https://i2.wp.com/pepejuegos.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/09/mortal-kombat-11-sindel-nintendo-switch-mortal-kombat-11-sindel0.png) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
     background-size: cover  !important;
}
```

html

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="background">
```

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Comment: Me he equivocado pues, pensaba que era el sitio ingles.. Traduzco. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

```
ion-content.background{
--background: url("tu url") center/cover fixed;
}
```